# Google Sign in on Android TV isn't working on the user's first login because onActivityResult is not being called?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tv, google-signin

I have a plugin I've written that performs google sign in within a fragment. The code is pretty textbook by the link below and works great on phones and tablets, but it fails on Android TV when the user first tries to login. After the user chooses their account, they get returned to a black screen.

For whatever reason subsequent logins work fine.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

After looking at the logcat I've found that onActivityResult isn't being called at all, and I think the culprit is the no touch account picker for Android TV not cleaning up. The reason I think this is that this is the main difference between other platforms, and when the sign in is called the second time the account picker doesn't show up and the log in works fine.

This is my code:

```
  public void startSignIn() {
    Log.d("sign in","starting sign in");
      Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
      startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
  }


  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    GoogleSignInHelper.logDebug("finishing sign in");
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
      }
    }
  }
```

As you may have noticed there are debug statements I've put in, and only "starting sign in" is getting logged. Has anyone implemented google sign in on android TV that might have experience with this?